# how to update product attribute value after new product save

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, product, admin, product-attribute

I wanna update product attribute value whenever new product will be added from admin in Magento 1.8. i used event observers but nothing happen my observer method is not calling  when new product added i used following code in config.xml

I tried below event in both global and admin section

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Nextgeni_MostLove>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Nextgeni_MostLove>
    </modules>

     <global>
        <models>
            <mostlove>
                <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mostlove_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mostlove>
            <validationmodel>
                <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Model</class>
            </validationmodel>
            <mostlove_mysql4>
                <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <mostlove>
                        <table>most_love_product</table>
                    </mostlove>
                </entities>
            </mostlove_mysql4>
        </models>

        <helpers>
            <mostlove>
                <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Helper</class>
                <!-- This will be the path of Helper Files -->
            </mostlove>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <mostlove>
                <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Block</class>
            </mostlove>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_featured>Nextgeni_MostLove_Catalog_Block_Product_Featured</product_featured>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>          
        </blocks>

         <resources>
            <mostlove_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Nextgeni_MostLove</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mostlove_setup>
            <mostlove_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mostlove_write>
            <mostlove_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mostlove_read>
        </resources>

        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <magedev_events_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductBefore</method>
                    </magedev_events_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events> 
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mostlove>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Nextgeni_MostLove</module>
                    <frontName>mostlove</frontName>
                </args>
            </mostlove>
        </routers>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mostlove>
                    <file>mostlove.xml</file>
                </mostlove>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <mostlove>
            <most_love_config>
                <showimage>1</showimage>    
                <displayText>Love</displayText>     
                <productLoveMin>0</productLoveMin>              
                <productLoveMax>0</productLoveMax>  
                <enableHeart>heart_icon.png</enableHeart>
                <disableHeart>heart_disable.png</disableHeart>
              </most_love_config>
        </mostlove>
    </default>

</config>
```

My Observer file code is

```
<?php
class Nextgeni_MostLove_Model_Observer
{



     public function catalog_product_save_before(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('You totally failed at that.'));
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getData()); exit;
    // do something here
    }

    public function applyAllRulesOnProduct($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('You totally failed at that.'));
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getData()); exit;
    // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind providing us with the whole thing please? as @Andreas von Studnitz suggested, we miss some of the xml part and we don't have your observer class either. Maybe you made a small typo in its name.

Comment: hi i updated my config file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have left out `<!-- Some code here-->`. I'd like to see the `<models>` part inside `<global>`. I expect the error to be there.
Try to change `<class>Nextgeni_MostLove/observer</class>` to `<class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Model_Observer</class>` or whatever the class of your observer is.

Another potential error: the `<events>` part should be inside `<global>`, `<frontend>` (not in your case) or `<adminhtml>`.

Comment: Thanks there is class name issue my problem is solved. now i using this observer 
<events>
   <catalog_product_save_before>
    <observers>
     <magedev_events_observer>
      <type>singleton</type>
      <class>Nextgeni_MostLove_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>saveProductBefore</method>
     </magedev_events_observer>
    </observers>
   </catalog_product_save_before>
  </events>